# Вызов хранимой процедуры с передачей параметра

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net

Есть веб-приложение, на странице содержится GridView с подключённой базой данных через SqlDataSource. Как можно вызвать хранимую процедуру (`StoredProcedure2`) и при вызове передать этой процедуре параметр? Я вызывал хранимую процедуру (другую хранимую процедуру  по имени `StoredProcedure1`, которая не требовала передачи в неё параметров путём:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "StoredProcedure1";

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
AS
 SELECT ID, Name, Surname FROM Table1 WHERE Name='Sania'

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2
 @Name VARCHAR(15)
AS
 SELECT ID, Name, Surname FROM Table1 WHERE Name=@Name
```

Comment: [Пример вызова хранимых процедур SQL Server](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post991355.html)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кому-то пригодится, пример вызова хранимой процедуры без параметров для с#,
SelectPole2 - это название хранимой процедуры

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;" +
              "database=Агрономія4;" +
              "Integrated Security=True");
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            conn.Open();
            myCmd.Connection = conn;
            myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCmd.CommandText = "SelectPole2";
            SqlDataReader rez;
            rez = myCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            GridView1.DataSource = rez;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
```